# Falha de conexão SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-azure

Estou recebendo a mensagem de erro abaixo ao tentar efetuar conexão com banco hospedado na AZURE através de uma aplicação WEB:

> An exception has been raiset that is likely due to transient failure. If you are connecting to Sql Azure database, consider using SqlAzureStrategy.

Desabilitei o firewall do banco para verificar se este poderia ser o problema, mas não resolveu.

Estou conseguindo conectar pelo SQL Server Management Studio, mas não pela aplicação.

A aplicação conecta com banco através do EF6

```
var usuario = Db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Login == login).FirstOrDefault();
            if (usuario != null && usuario.ProfissionalID.HasValue)
            {
                usuario.Profissional = Db.Profissional.Where(x => x.ProfissionalID == usuario.ProfissionalID).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return usuario;
```

Vi em ougtro artigo da Microsoft para implementar este trecho de código para resolver o problema:

```
public class DbContextConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public DbContextConfiguration()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy(
                "System.Data.SqlClient",
                () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
        }
    }
```

Fiz isso, mas ta me parecendo que ele faz varias tentativas de conexão a cada, até que uma seja bem sucedida.

Mas me parece que o servidor esta instável, pois a pouco não consegui conexão, utilizando SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.

Agora mesmo recebi outra mensagem de erro:

Maximum number of retries (1) exceeded while executing database operations with 'SqlAzureExecutionStrategy'.

Comment: Você está usando C#? Poste o código da sua conexão

Comment: Tá usando `SqlAzureStrategy`?

Comment: acho que o problema não é a conexão e sim algo que vc está tentando executar e ai está dando o erro acima. o sql do azure é bem chato mesmo.

Comment: posta a string de conexao, removendo o nome do database, user e senha.

Comment: <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.ControleHorasContext.csdl|res://*/Context.ControleHorasContext.ssdl|res://*/Context.ControleHorasContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXX;initial catalog=XXX;persist security info=True;user id=XXX;password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não creio que seja um problema de banco de dados, senão você veria um erro muito diferente desse atual, algo como dizendo que o endereço de IP não tem permissão de acesso pelo firewall.

Ao invés disso eu tentaria olhar essa resposta do Markus Wagner onde ele diz sobre os parametros de `maxRetryCount` e `maxDelay`. Eu acho que esse deva ser um bom começo para garantir que seu código está bem preparado para trabalhar com essas classes.

Em seguida, existe um bom número de melhores práticas publicadas sobre como trabalhar com Azure SQL service. Eu procuraria me certificar que você está atendendo todas essas melhores práticas e tentasse ajustar onde fosse possível. Eu tentaria:

- Minimizar a latencia de rede
- Reduzir o uso de rede implementando cache de aplicação
- Gerenciar a conexão de rede, mantendo-a aberta o mínimo possível
- Tunar seu queries SQL
- Implementar logica de múltiplas tentativas.

[Traduzido da resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430829/2520523)